# Why does attribute 'bessel_i0e' keep disappearing in my conda envs?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have been learning Tensorflow using Jupyter Notebook. I keep running into this error where I will restart a kernel on a notebook file, and when I type `import tensorflow as tf` I get following error

```
module 'tensorflow.python.ops.special_math_ops' has no attribute 'bessel_i0e'
```

With a bunch of other text. I have multiple conda envs, and when I switch to another env it works fine, even though they use the same cached version of tensorflow. I really have no idea what is happening.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely uninstall and reinstall tensorflow and keras to get rid of this error.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu tensorflow keras
pip install --upgrade tensorflow keras
```

did the trick for me.